# How to provide a custom component for the Algolia autocomplete searchbox without creating a custom renderer?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, algolia

I'm using the autocomplete feature of Algolia with a few plugins to display suggestions or recent searches.

While implementing this, I use the templating capabilities of autocomplete to provide custom components for suggestions or other autocompletions which are rendered in the autocomplete panel.

However, I want to change the component for the searchbox itself and hook into it without creating a rederer with 'autocomplete-core'.

I tried to use the 'createAutocomplete' from the core library but this would mean I have to implement all functionality provided by 'autocomplete-js' from scratch.

This is the searchbox' default look, but I want to use a custom component instead:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?